# How to mount NTFS drive with read write permission on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, mount, ntfs, 18.10

I have installed my Ubuntu 18.10 on a SSD and I also have a another drive which is formatted as NTFS file system. When I click on mount it mounts that drive but I am only able to see the files. I can't seem to write into it.

I am not dual booting. I only have Ubuntu installed as a Operating System.

Can anyone please help me on how to setup my NTFS drive to auto mount at startup with Read and Write Access?

Comment: @Pilot6 I have seen other post but I couldn't figure out what to do. I'm totally new to ubuntu. Can you please tell me what I should write into my `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: `fstab` is not the issue. The problem is with hibernation. Do you have Windows installed?

Comment: @Pilot6 No. I only have ubuntu installed

Comment: I would suggest you check the reason it's mounting as read-only, it's either an error condition (needing fix), OR you are trying to mount a windows 10 hibernated/fast-boot system (where the file-system is not in a safe state, so to avoid issues Ubuntu is letting you read-only).

Comment: @guiverc Can you please tell me how can I fix this? I don't know much regarding this.

Comment: You can try this https://askubuntu.com/a/532753/167850

Comment: When you `mount` it (esp. if done from terminal where you are shown the reason), you can check system logs to see the messages (hidden by a GUI).  Look with `dmesg` for the messages for the mount.  I'm suggesting you check for a reason for safety reasons, as usually a RO mount has a reason (and forcing it is unwise where you value the data)

Comment: @guiverc  didn't mount it from terminal. The drive was shown in my file manager so I just selected mount from right click menu on drive icon. Do I have to paste dmesg on terminal and look for error ?

Comment: I guessed that (otherwise you'd already know the reason), which is why I mentioned `dmesg` which shows the messages hidden by your gui/file-manager, or lets you re-view the messages that you saw on terminal.

Comment: @guiverc How can I view the error. When I entered dmesg on terminal I get a lot of text output. I don't know much regarding this. This is what I got https://pastebin.com/FagZtUu8

Comment: Which is why I suggested you check after/when you `mount` it (ie. it's easy to see as it just occurred & is at the bottom of the list [of events]).  *I didn't look, if not there look with `journalctl -a`*

Comment: @guiverc uploading that result right after I mounted the drive. I couldn't find anything regarding this.

Comment: @guiverc I have gone through `journalctl -a` couldn't find anything regarding a mounting error.

Comment: An example of a fstab entry for a NTFS partition is `/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD800JD-75MSA3_WD-WMAM9APE5111-part1    /windows/C      ntfs-3g users,gid=users,fmask=133,dmask=022,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0 `  (*I prefer using UUID to mount, but I don't have a NTFS partition on any running system I can login currently to test an entry for you; I grabbed this line from a backup dataset; I believe that [example] was for a windows 7 dual-boot hdd*)